# React Testing Library - i18n translations not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to test a component, here's the component, simplified:

```
const Block = () => {
   const { t } = useTranslation();
  
   return <p data-testid="text">{t('some.text')}</p>;
}
```

Then I have this test:

```
test('That the text is correct', () => {
  const wrapper = render(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Block />
    </I18nextProvider>
  );

  expect(wrapper.getByTestId('text')).toHaveTextContent('Hello!');
});
```

The i18n is my config file, which looks like this:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en'
    debug: false,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```

But I'm still getting:

```
Expect element to have text content:
   Hello!
Received:
   some.text
```

My suspicion is that the Backend plugin is what's making it not work.

Comment: i think `t('some.text')` shuld be `t(some.text)`

Comment: Nope quotes are needed, it works in the component, it just doesn't work in the test

Comment: One option to get the test working is to mock the `useTranslation` hook with jest.mock... Take a look at this https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Comment: I tried but I can't use the translation files, I have to manually put the object with the translations in the resources field

Comment: Damn i have this issue too. Did you solve it by now @nick ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue simply by **importing the i18n configuration file im my test**.

First I tried the [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing) but would still get the same error. Finally, after some fixes my test works and it looks like that:

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import myComponent from "path/to/MyComponent";
import "path/to/i18n";

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render input with placeholder', () => {
      render(<MyComponent/>);
      const placeholderItem = screen.getByPlaceholderText('translation');
      expect(placeholderItem).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
}
```

An the component looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export default function MyComponent() {
    const {t} = useTranslation();

    return (<Input placeholder={t("key") ?? ''}/>);
}
```

So, the game changer for me was to **import the** `"path/to/i18n"` **i18n configuration file** in my test